# Как получить данные через PDO fetch и Update

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть запрос такого вида:

```
UPDATE 
    books
SET
    rating = @rating := (SELECT 
        ROUND(AVG(post_rating)) AS book_rating
    FROM
        posts
    WHERE 
        book_id = 5)
WHERE id = 5;

SELECT @rating AS book_rating;
```

По факту выполняется два запроса UPDATE и SELECT и результат отображается как book_rating = 3.
При попытке разобрать данные:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

я получаю ошибку: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error.

Такая ошибка может появляться, когда пытаются получить данные из UPDATE. То есть $stmt->fetch видит только первый запрос UPDATE, но не второй запрос SELECT @rating.

Подскажите, можно ли каким-то образом получить данные с запросом такого вида?

Answer (score 0):

Очень просто.

UPDATE и SELECT - это **два** запроса, и соответственно, надо выполнить два запроса к БД:

```
$pdo->query("UPDATE 
            books 
        SET
            rating = @rating := (SELECT 
            ROUND(AVG(post_rating)) AS book_rating
        FROM
            posts
        WHERE 
            book_id = 5)
        WHERE id = 5");
$rating = $pdo->query("SELECT @rating AS book_rating")->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: А можно ли сделать обновление и выборку значения каким-то образом в одном запросе?

Comment: А зачем? В принципе, человек может многое. Но он всегда должен держать перед собой картинку про троллейбус из батона хлеба.жпг